# No view found for id 0x7f090058 for fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm doing an app that uses Google Maps APIs (with two separate maps), and I want to use a navigation drawer to switch between the two maps (fragments).

I created the main activity with the pre-compiled Navigation Drawer Activity in android studio, and here is the pieces of code:

- The main activity uses this layout:

**activity_main_activity2.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="it.radonmap.radonmap.MainActivity2">

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"           android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:name="it.radonmap.radonmap.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the code which calls the .replace() method:

```
 private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //do something
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragPunti();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager;
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerPunti,fragment).commit();

    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

**FragPunti.java**

```
public class FragPunti extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

public FragPunti(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_punti, null);
    return rootView;
     }
}
```

**frag_punti.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/containerPunti">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/framePunti"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="Punti"/>
    </FrameLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```

And here is the **logcat** trace:

```
04-30 19:17:45.823  20909-20909/it.radonmap.radonmap E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: it.radonmap.radonmap, PID: 20909
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090058 (it.radonmap.radonmap:id/containerPunti) for fragment FragPunti{36b6aaa5 #2 id=0x7f090058}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:945)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

I had already look for a solution but with no results. 
Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Here `replace(R.id.containerPunti,fragment)` you should use an id that can actually be found in your activity's xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass id of container for fragment, and that's a view in which you want to show fragment. It is in activity, not in fragment you want to show. So change `replace(R.id.containerPunti, fragment)` to `replace(R.id.container, fragment)`.

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't work. If I debug my application, exceptions don't occur, but the Fragment doesn't change..

Comment: Maybe its because FrameLayout and both fragments all have width and height set to match_parent.

Comment: Can you advice me how to set them?

Comment: It depends on how you want it to look, but setting height of FrameLayout and fragments to wrap_content should work

Comment: I tried to set their to wrap_content but it still doesn't work. Have I to put the textView inside of the FrameLayout of the main_activity's xml or leave it into the other xml (frag_punti.xml)?

Comment: TextView should stay in frag_punti.xml. And in onCreateView in fragment it should be `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_punti, container);`

Comment: I tried it and the logcat shows this: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`
            How can I solve it?

Comment: Try with `inflate(R.layout.frag_punti, container, false)`

Comment: Already tried it but now it does the same thing as before, that is the one of the first comment. (If I debug my application, exceptions don't occur, but the Fragment doesn't change.. )

Comment: I solved it. Basically I had to call `replace(R.id.drawer_layout, fragment)`. I have been passing the wrong parent all the time. Now I have other errors but if I can't solve them I will post another question. I'll mark your question as accepted because it helped me understanding more about Fragments etc. Thanks for your patience!